# OS X Yosemite Crashes Frequently

Tags: macos, macbook-pro, crash

So I installed OS X Yosemite almost a week ago, and within this time frame have experienced 2 crashes. Basically, the OS freezes, and then shuts down, and doesn't start up again until I press the power button myself. I am unaware whom I should report this problem to. Furthermore, it doesn't seem that the problem is being reported to apple since no message indicating such reporting is presented after the crash. Any suggestions on what actions I should take? I have a mid-2012 15' RMBP.

Edit: System Log

```
11/14/14 10:51:34.062 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.system) Could not import service from caller: path = /Library/LaunchDaemons/PPPMonitord.plist, caller = launchd.1, error = 111: Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments
11/14/14 10:51:35.721 PM discoveryd[51]: Basic Sockets UDS FD=3 ERROR: failed to get effective user ID, errno 0
11/14/14 10:51:36.933 PM WindowServer[97]: Set a breakpoint at CGSLogError to catch errors as they are logged.
11/14/14 10:52:21.044 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua) Could not import service from caller: path = /Library/LaunchAgents/Swapper.plist, caller = loginwindow.67, error = 111: Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments
11/14/14 10:52:21.057 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua) Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.pluginkit.pkd.plist, error = 17: File exists
11/14/14 10:52:21.057 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua) Failed to bootstrap path: path = /Library/LaunchAgents/Swapper.plist, error = 111: Invalid or missing Program/ProgramArguments
11/14/14 10:52:21.057 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.user.501.100006.Aqua) Failed to bootstrap path: path = /System/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.mbpluginhost.user.plist, error = 17: File exists
11/14/14 10:52:21.084 PM otherbsd[188]: Failed to bootstrap agent: path = /Users/User/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.FolderActions.folders.plist, error = 119: Service is disabled
11/14/14 10:52:21.084 PM otherbsd[188]: Failed to bootstrap agent: path = /Users/User/Library/LaunchAgents/com.apple.FolderActions.enabled.plist, error = 119: Service is disabled
11/14/14 10:52:21.342 PM pboard[208]: Attempt to unlink previous shared memory during startup returned an error.  Continuing...
11/14/14 10:52:22.271 PM logind[68]: -[SessionManager getClient:withRole:inAuditSession:]:241: ERROR: No session dictionary for audit session 100010
11/14/14 10:52:22.271 PM logind[68]: _SMGetSessionAgent:73: ERROR: __SMGetClientForAuditSessionAgent failed 2
11/14/14 10:52:22.272 PM IMDPersistenceAgent[242]: SACShieldWindowShowing:925: ERROR: NULL response
11/14/14 10:52:26.836 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.BKAgentService.293) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.BKAgentService.xpc
11/14/14 10:52:26.837 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.BKAgentService.293) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/BookKit.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.BKAgentService.xpc
11/14/14 10:52:29.163 PM discoveryd[51]: Basic DNSResolver  Error 9 on socket - this might be a closed socket
11/14/14 10:52:29.479 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:52:31.251 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.om.apple.photostream-agent.310) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Frameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PhotoApps.DevicePropertyReader.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/PhotoStreamAgent.app
11/14/14 10:52:31.255 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.om.apple.photostream-agent.310) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Frameworks/PhotoFoundation.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.PhotoApps.DevicePropertyReader.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /Applications/iPhoto.app/Contents/Library/LoginItems/PhotoStreamAgent.app
11/14/14 10:52:31.763 PM com.apple.Preview.TrustedBookmarksService[355]: Failed to resolve bookmark data at index: 0; bookmark was STALE; error: <no error>
11/14/14 10:52:31.827 PM NotificationCenter[304]: Layout still needs update after calling -[NSView layout].  NSView or one of its superclasses may have overridden -layout without calling super. Or, something may have dirtied layout in the middle of updating it.  Both are programming errors in Cocoa Autolayout.  The former is pretty likely to arise if some pre-Cocoa Autolayout class had a method called layout, but it should be fixed.
11/14/14 10:52:31.862 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:52:36.964 PM talagent[201]: CGSConnectionRelinquishWindowRights(cid, result, reservedRights): CGError 1001 on line 875
11/14/14 10:52:52.517 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:52:53.249 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:52:53.650 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:52:58.386 PM storeaccountd[225]: NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
11/14/14 10:52:58.775 PM storeaccountd[225]: NSURLConnection/CFURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9824)
11/14/14 10:52:59.285 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:52:59.307 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:01.935 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:01.939 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:01.942 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:01.942 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:01.999 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:02.051 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:02.055 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:02.066 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:02.110 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:02.687 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[213]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff71a9cc60> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff71a9cf70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>
11/14/14 10:53:08.372 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:12.713 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:12.713 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:12.900 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.731 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.733 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.738 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.739 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.742 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.744 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.745 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.746 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.748 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.750 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.751 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.755 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.755 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.789 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:14.790 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:21.271 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:21.274 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:21.281 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:21.281 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:53:30.769 PM lsuseractivityd[240]: -[LSUserActivityClientProcess doUpdateUserActivityInfo:makeCurrent:completionHandler:], refusing to register user activity from client, and returning error Error Domain=LSContinuityErrorDomain Code=-108 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (LSContinuityErrorDomain error -108.)" for item <__NSConcreteUUID 0x7f91e5204f70> 6F15C413-2978-4FA9-B545-758A3CEB493E NSUserActivityTypeBrowsingWeb (LSUserActivityClientProcess.m #1148)
11/14/14 10:54:00.272 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_response;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:00.272 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f8029793f80 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_response failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:00.381 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_blob_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:00.381 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f8029793f80 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_blob_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:00.430 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_receiver_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:00.430 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f8029793f80 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_receiver_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:00.440 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=PRAGMA incremental_vacuum;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:00.440 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f8029793f80 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Vacuum failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:00.711 PM com.apple.xpc.launchd[1]: (com.apple.xpc.launchd.domain.pid.quicklookd.478) Path not allowed in target domain: type = pid, path = /Library/Frameworks/iTunesLibrary.framework/Versions/A/XPCServices/com.apple.iTunesLibraryService.xpc error = 147: The specified service did not ship in the requestor's bundle, origin = /System/Library/Frameworks/QuickLook.framework/Versions/A/Resources/quicklookd.app
11/14/14 10:54:01.388 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_response;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:01.388 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f80297971e0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_response failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:01.391 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_blob_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:01.391 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f80297971e0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_blob_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:01.392 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_receiver_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:01.392 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f80297971e0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_receiver_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:01.399 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=PRAGMA incremental_vacuum;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:01.400 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f80297971e0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Vacuum failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:02.238 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_response;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:02.238 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_response failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:02.243 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_blob_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:02.244 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_blob_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:02.244 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_receiver_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:02.244 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_receiver_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:02.245 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=PRAGMA incremental_vacuum;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:02.245 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Vacuum failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:02.493 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
11/14/14 10:54:06.250 PM CoreServicesUIAgent[213]: unexpected message <OS_xpc_error: <error: 0x7fff71a9cc60> { count = 1, contents =
    "XPCErrorDescription" => <string: 0x7fff71a9cf70> { length = 18, contents = "Connection invalid" }
}>
11/14/14 10:54:07.818 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_response;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:07.818 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_response failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:07.822 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_blob_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:07.822 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_blob_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:07.822 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=DELETE from cfurl_cache_receiver_data;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:07.822 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Delete from cfurl_cache_receiver_data failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
11/14/14 10:54:07.823 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: execSQLStatement:onConnection:toCompletionWithRetry - SQL=PRAGMA incremental_vacuum;, error-code=11, error-message=database disk image is malformed
11/14/14 10:54:07.823 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: ERROR: NSURLStorageURLCacheDB deleteAllResponses: dbConnection=0x7f802952f3a0 DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db Vacuum failed:database disk image is malformed ErrCode: 11.
```

Comment: @JasonC  One thing that did fix the problem is switching to chrome. On closer inspection, I found that I got log messages relating to the integrated graphics card. My hypothesis is that since chrome mainly uses the dedicated graphics card, it mitigates the problem which is caused by graphics card switching (I have read elsewhere that this is a common problem among MBPr users)

Comment: "I am unaware whom I should report this problem to."  http://bugreport.apple.com

Answer (score 1):

For one Safari is making lots of trouble, flooding your boot. (it is possible you have a Virus).

```
11/14/14 10:52:59.285 PM nsurlstoraged[219]: Error: stepSQLStatement:toCompletionWithRetry - stepping returned unhandled result=11, DB=/Users/User/Library/Caches/com.apple.Safari/Cache.db
```

To fix that lets clear the Safari Cache files.

Follow the instructions here by [Linc Davis](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6648836).

And/Or delete it here `/private/var/folders/xl/fxfqtrn56kb_hn6s2rcns3p80000gn/C/com.apple.Safari`

If none helped try following:

Step 1:  sudo rm -f ~/Library/Cookies/Cookies.binarycookies

enter password

Step 2: Select Clear History and Website Data  from Safari menu; click Clear History button in dialog box. This resets Safari

Step 3: Then force quit Safari from the context menu by clicking Cnt + icon in the dock.

Step 4: Finally, fully power down (Shut Down not Restart) the machine and then restart.

Comment: I actually tried all of the above, I also tried verifying my disk as well as the permissions, and ended up repairing any disk errors. While I am yet to crash again, the log line noted above still shows up in my log, several times.

Comment: It has been a while, so checking with you to hear if you had another crash ? or did the clearing the cache helped.